# How big the window could be when using spark stream?

Tags: apache-spark

We have some stream data need to be calculated and considering use spark stream to do it.

We need to generate three kinds of reports. The reports are based on

1. The last 5 minutes data
2. The last 1 hour data
3. The last 24 hour data

The frequency of reports is 5 minutes.

After reading the docs, the most obvious way to solve this seems to set up a spark stream with 5 minutes interval and two window which are 1 hour and 1 day.

But I am worrying that if the window is too big for one day and one hour. I do not have much experience on spark stream, so what is the window length in your environment?